# How to use impact radius tracking id (subid1/subid2..)?

Tags: affiliate, affiliates

I am trying to add a tracking id to impact radius affiliate link.
I couldn't find anything about this in "Impact Radius" site so I made some research on google and find some blogs that mention about field name "subid1" that you can add to the affiliate link.

My question is, can I send anything I want in this field or I limited by something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

after talking to impact radius support I got an answer.
if you are "impact radius" member you can read it here: 
https://help.impactradius.com/hc/en-us/articles/202938699-SubID-and-SharedID.

In shortly, like I said, there is a field name "subId1" and also "subId2", "subId3" and "sharedId" that you can enter any custom id you want to add.

subId1 and subId 2: alphanumeric 64 characters
subId3: alphanumeric 32 characters
sharedId: string 32 characters.

using like this:
http://trackingdomain.ojrq.net/c/mpid/adid/campaignid?subId1=value1&subId2=value2&subId3=value3&sharedId=value4.

I hope it will help anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can get it worked with Vanity Urls like this.

petalcard.whij.net/your_unique_url?subId1=something&subId2=sdfsdf

Remember I is capital in subId.

Comment: The subIds works on url without https. something like http://domain/unique?subId2={clickid}